# Videos in Totem kills X server

Tags: 11.10, drivers, xorg, video, totem

*Using oneiric, up-to-date.*

**01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter (rev 10)**

With the SiS driver available in the repositories my videos and movies play smoothly, but I have a desktop resolution of 1024x768 only.

With the driver in https://github.com/hellnest/xf86-video-sismedia-0.9.1 I have a desktop resolution at 1280x800, but if I try to play any video, the X server is killed and return to the login screen.

How can I correct this behaviour?

Comment: I just discovered this issue with any use of video. If I try to shoot with the Cheese, for example, X is killed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to recompile with this patch:
https://github.com/hellnest/xf86-video-sismedia-0.9.1/commit/60823291

solved the problem for me